# Apache 2.4 server not reading .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We are setting up a new server, where we have installed Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.2. In our code structure we have an .htaccess file, but Apache is not accessing it.

We have modify the `httpd.conf` file and enabled the `mod_rewrite` and set

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And restart Apache after this, but it is not picking .htaccess file from location - `htdocs/myProject/.htaccess`

Comment: Maybe check what `AccessFileName` is set to? (`.htaccess` would be the default, but from the outside we can’t tell if someone maybe modified that already.)

Comment: strange but its work for me, in httpd.conf file, I have change -  `<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>` to `<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>`  And it work for me ..

Answer (score 0):

strange but its work for me, in httpd.conf file, I have change -

```
<IfModule dir_module> 
   DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>
```

to

```
<IfModule dir_module> 
   DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 
</IfModule>
```

And it work for me.

Thanks